# Ionic 2 + Facebook (Cannot find 'facebookConnectPlugin')

Tags: facebook, cordova-plugins, ionic2

I am creating an application using [Ionic 2](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/) that will make some calls to Facebook API. I followed the steps from [documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/Facebook/) and installed the cordova plugin [cordova-plugin-facebook4](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4).

Now I'm trying to authenticate the user, but without success. My login page:

```
import {Page} from 'ionic-framework/ionic';


@Page({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/page1/page1.html',
})
export class Page1 {
  login() {
    facebookConnectPlugin.login(
      ['email'],
      response => {
        console.log(response);
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

When I run the application with:

```
ionic serve
```

I get the following error in the terminal:

[image]

When I click on the login button I get the following error in the console:

[image]

And when I try to build the application to run on a real device I get the following error in the console:

[image]

I think I have to import the plugin to be able to use, but how?

Answer (score 3):

try this.

install ionic-native `npm install ionic-native --save`
after this , you will need to import facebook `import {Facebook} from 'ionic-native`'

you can now use your facebook plugin this way

```
  fblogin(){
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      Facebook.login(["email"]).then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
       })
    })
  }
```

make sure to put each permissions into separate string in the array

Answer (score 2):

facebookConnectPlugin Cordova plugin does not work on browser, but if you try to run it on an emulator, it works fine. As per the [instructions](https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4/blob/master/docs/browser/README.md) on jeduan's repo, you can get this to work on web apps, but I haven't tried it because it wasn't a necessity for me.

You can ignore `Cannot find name facebookConnectPlugin` error because it's just TypeScript complaining. It should work just fine after Transpiling to JS.

Not sure why you are getting build errors. Documentation has one major omission which could be the reason (Refer [this issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5961)). You need to pass your Facebook App ID and App Name (you can get it from [developer.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/))

`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-facebook4 --variable APP_ID="123456789" --variable APP_NAME="myApplication"`

For Android, you also need to generate a key hash and provide it to Facebook. If you are on OSX, you can generate a keyhash like this:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

Answer (score 1):

Friends,

I have done this and got it working. You need to register your app with the facebook developer portal and then add the cordova plugin and then write code. It's a lengthy process.

Detailed instructions given here - http://tphangout.com/?p=204

Hope this helps you, Thanks.

Comment: I followed the instructions in the link you provided. But I am getting an error when I run the app in android device that is, `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. To use this URL you must add a valid native platform in your App's settings.`

Comment: I am sorry bro. That post was made with an older version of Ionic. I have made an updated post now. Why don't you try these steps - http://tphangout.com/ionic-2-facebook-graph-api-updated/

Comment: Yeah, now I am able to login, but I am unable to get my friends list(all friends) on fb. Can you please help me on this? I don't know the api call exactly on graph api explorer.